# how can i assign query result of sequelize to a property of a object

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I defined a object A in which i need to store some objects.
How can i assign the query result to the property of the object.

Here is my example code.

```
function A(Job){
    this.job = Job;
    this.location ={};
    models.locations.findOne({
        where:{
            job_id:this.job.id
        }
    }).then(function(location){
        //what should i do here to store it in A.locaiton
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hold the reference of `this` into a `that` property (or any other name you prefer) and then use `that.location`. For example:

```
function A(Job) {
    var that = this;
    that.job = Job;
    that.location = {};
    models.locations.findOne({
        where: {
            job_id: this.job.id
        }
    }).then(function (location) {
        that.location = location;
    });
}
```

Hope this helps.